# bootstrap accordion show data on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

So this is a standard bootstrap accordion.

I am trying to make it switch to the next section upon mouseover of the heading.

I can get the first command to execute to hide, but the second show changes everything. I just want it to show the content relating to the header below it.

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#accordionuser .panel-heading").mouseover(
    function() {    $('#accordionuser .panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
                    $('#accordionuser .panel-collapse').collapse('show');
                        }
);
</script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordionuser">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionuser" href="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionuser" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionuser" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
      minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
      commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



       </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand you, but I hope this will solve your problem:

```
$('#accordionuser .panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
$(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/yavxazv6/

Comment: thank you - you understood pretty well. i am trying to move what i previously had in the jqueryui to bootstrap with this simple function, however, this does not seem to be as stable with panels moving when they're not supposed to. any thoughts on how to make it more stable. thanks. jquery code   $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            event: "mouseover"
        });
    });